# Bytecode enhancement not working

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am using below link as a reference to implement lazy loading of an image from PostgreSQL DB:
[URL](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

In my User entity I declared byte array field:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] avatar;
```

In pom.xml file I included hiberante enhancement plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>enhance</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

The issue is that when I fetch User entity from the DB, avatar byte array is also loaded, which I don't want.

I understand that hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin is supposed to enhance/alter User.class file, this didn't happen.

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:

I execute enhance goal: 
org.hibernate.orm.tooling:hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin:enhance
In consol I got message: 
"Skipping Hibernate bytecode enhancement plugin execution since no feature is enabled" 
I checked plugin jar file hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin-5.3.1.Final.jar and i see bellow code:

```
@Mojo(name="enhance", defaultPhase=LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, 
requiresDependencyResolution=ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME)
public class MavenEnhancePlugin
extends AbstractMojo
{
private List<File> sourceSet = new ArrayList();
@Component
private BuildContext buildContext;
@Parameter(property="base", defaultValue="${project.build.outputDirectory}")
private String base;
@Parameter(property="dir", defaultValue="${project.build.outputDirectory}")
private String dir;
@Parameter(property="failOnError", defaultValue="true")
private boolean failOnError = true;
@Parameter(property="enableLazyInitialization", defaultValue="false")
private boolean enableLazyInitialization;
@Parameter(property="enableDirtyTracking", defaultValue="false")
private boolean enableDirtyTracking;
@Parameter(property="enableAssociationManagement", defaultValue="false")
private boolean enableAssociationManagement;
@Parameter(property="enableExtendedEnhancement", defaultValue="false")
private boolean enableExtendedEnhancement;

private boolean shouldApply()
{
    return (this.enableLazyInitialization) || (this.enableDirtyTracking) || 
    (this.enableAssociationManagement) || (this.enableExtendedEnhancement);
}

public void execute()
throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{
if (!shouldApply())
{
  getLog().warn("Skipping Hibernate bytecode enhancement plugin execution since no feature is enabled");
  return;
}
.
.
.
}
```

Looks like shouldApply() method returns false, not sure why since I set properties(enableLazyInitialization) in pom file to be true.

Comment: You're saying that when you built the application using maven, the enhancement step did not execute?

Comment: I am saying that that avatar is loaded when i fetch User object from DB.

Comment: How to verify if enhancement step is executed?

Comment: I typically see output from the enhancement plugin when i run maven build from the command line.  Do you not?  If not, perhaps the plugin isn't being executed by maven?

Comment: I run goal explicitly: org.hibernate.orm.tooling:hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin:5.3.1.Final:enhance.In Console I can see message: "[WARNING] Skipping Hibernate bytecode enhancement plugin execution since no feature is enabled".

Comment: Sounds like a maven configuration issue, the configuration block isn't being properly read by the plugin for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't intend to use the plugin to participate in some phases of the build lifecycle, then you should not use executions. Try this configuration in your pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                <enableDirtyTracking>false</enableDirtyTracking>
                <enableAssociationManagement>false</enableAssociationManagement>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </plugin>
```