# How to setup Hibernate Gradle plugin in kotlin-script?

Tags: hibernate, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to setup the **Hibernate gradle plugin** in my Gradle Kotlin-script project, to no avail.

I followed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442509/2041863) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35581674/2041863), my configuration is as follows:

**settings.gradle.kts:**

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.hibernate.orm") {
                useModule("org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
  ...
  id("org.hibernate.orm") version "5.4.9.Final"
  ...
}

...

hibernate {
  enhance {  }
}
```

I am getting an error from Gradle:

```
  Line 193:   enhance {}
                      ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but (Closure<Any!>..Closure<*>?) was expected
```

I also tried with the following `hibernate` block:

```
hibernate {
  enhance {
    enableLazyInitialization = true
    enableDirtyTracking = true
    enableAssociationManagement = true
  }
}
```

but i'm just getting more errors:

```
  Line 193:   enhance {
                      ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but (Closure<Any!>..Closure<*>?) was expected

  Line 194:     enableLazyInitialization = true
                ^ Unresolved reference: enableLazyInitialization

  Line 195:     enableDirtyTracking = true
                ^ Unresolved reference: enableDirtyTracking

  Line 196:     enableAssociationManagement = true
                ^ Unresolved reference: enableAssociationManagement
```

Anyone knows how to make this work in Kotlin-script?

Comment: can you try import `import org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.EnhanceExtension`,

Comment: Also add `hibernate {
 enhance(closureOf<EnhanceExtension> { enableLazyInitialization = true
  enableDirtyTracking = true
  enableAssociationManagement = true
 })
}`, remove older config you have, rest all will remain same.

Comment: Thanks, Gradle doesn't complain anymore, however it seems my classes are not enhanced, even after a `gradle clean`. When i check the decompiled class there is nothing that looks like hibernate enhancements in my classes.

Comment: wouldn't that be an another issue, Ref: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-see-if-bytecode-enhancement-works-or-not/1044/4, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50570793/2987755

Comment: that's the link i was looking at, but i can't make it work with kotlin sourceSets, i think that's the problem. I have 100% kotlin code, no java code, and all my code in `src/main/kotlin`

Comment: Got, I really hate the kotlin gradle syntax. Nothing works as expected. Regreting every day, I ever used it.